# Losing ssh connection

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have a CentOS server where I try running fail2ban & iptables (don't like firewalld so I installed the package "iptables-services").

Using iptables with the following rules in a script "/etc/init.d/iptables.rules" launched at startup:

```
#!/bin/sh

# flush all
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Deny i/o
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Established co
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# loopback
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# ICMP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# SSH
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

Changed ssh port to 2222 in sshd_config but when I reboot I definitely lose ssh connection. Pretty sure I forgot something stupid but don't see what.

Have you an idea?

Comment: Did you add SELinux label to that new port?

Comment: SELinux is disabled.

Comment: BTW if port 2222 is in your server, you need to have `--sport` (source port) and not `--dport`. But this is not the real problem.

Comment: 3 times i try by fully reinstall centos. Everytime, i lose ssh connection when i enable iptables. Cant see what i miss ...